# What is the correct way to give information to a method?

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to add inputs to a method. I don't think the method can access the variables I am calling. It needs to return the bigger of two strings

I have tried changing what the output should be and if it is static or void. I have also tried moving the variables around with no success.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String one = "This is the first string.";
    String two = "This is the second string.";
}

public static String max(String one, String two) {
    if (one.length() > two.length()) {
        return one;
    } else {
        return two;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be "This is the second string." because the second string is larger than the first string.

Comment: All you're doing in your `main` method is declaring two local `String` variables and initializing them. You're not actually invoking the `max` method.

Comment: within `#main`, try: `System.out.println(max(one, two));`, this will print the result of `max(...)`.

Comment: On that note, I'd kick a visit over to the [Oracle Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), which will go extremely in depth on learning java

Comment: You never call the `max` method. And if length `one==two` it will return wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Sop statement and call the max method inside you will get to  expected o/p...check the below code

```
`public static String max(String one, String two) {
if (one.length() > two.length()) {
    return one;
} else {
    return two;
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String one = "This is the first string.";
    String two = "This is the second string.";
    System.out.println(max(one,two));
}
}`
```